# Running cronjob

Tags: bash, scripting, cron

've been puzzling over cronjobs for the last few hours.  I've read documentation and examples.  I understand the basics and concepts, but haven't gotten anything to work.  So I would appreciate some help with this total noob dilemma.

The ultimate goal is to schedule the execution of a django function every day.  Before I get that far, I want to know that I can schedule any old script to run, first once, then on a regular basis.

So I want to:
1) Write a simple script (perhaps a bash script) that will allow me to determine that yes, it did indeed run successfully, or that it failed.
2) schedule this script to run at the top of the hour

I tried writing a bash script that simple output some text to the terminal:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "The script ran"
```

Then I dropped this into a .txt file

```
MAILTO = *****.******@gmail.com
05 * * * * /home/vadmin/development/test.sh
```

But nothing happened.  I'm sure I did *many* things wrong.  Where do I start to fix all of this?

Comment: Hi Ed. You might be better off asking this on serverfault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crontab does not send emails by itself, and defining `MAILTO` variable doesn't change its mind. You need to do something like this:

First, make sure that `mail -s ADDRESS` is actually of sending email from your box.
Then invoke `crontab -e` to edit crontab file. Put something like this:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
MAILTO=dude@gmail.com
BASH_ENV=/home/dude/.bash_profile
05 * * * Mon-Fri echo "Hello from Cron script" | mail -s "My Script Output" "${MAILTO}"
```

Save the file and close editor, cron should pick up changes. This should work and you should get email. Then you can replace `echo "Hello from Cron script"` with your script.

Hope it helps. Good luck!

Comment: You're right that `crontab` doesn't send mail, but `cron` **does**. You don't have to explicitly pipe to `mail`. Any output to stdout that is not redirected will be mailed (assuming that mail is working).

Comment: @Dennis: Hm, I didn't know about it. Many times I had `MAILTO` in config but haven't got a single email... Maybe there is something else behind this. Thanks for note anyway.

Comment: Did it have `>filename` or `>/dev/null` at the end of the entry? Did the script do any redirection internally?

Comment: @Dennis: Maybe, I can't say for sure now. The only thing I know is that redirecting explicitly works for sure and, the most importantly, you can send output of different jobs to different email addresses.